# Desktop background "freezes" in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, unity

I'm experiencing an odd problem with my desktop, which I'm unable to find any solutions (or reproduces) on the web, partly because for any search terms I can think of, I come up with a lot of hits that don't relate to my problem...

The problem I'm seeing is that the desktop "freezes", so that what was shown on the desktop before is "left there" until something else is placed on top of it. I realize this explanation isn't perfect, so please see the screenshot below.

[image: Desktop freeze]

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 on an ASUS N53, and have followed most of the advice [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Asus_N53), but without success. I don't even know where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Have you tried filing a bug?

Comment: No, not yet. Since I have a model which I know has some problems with the graphics drivers I wanted to see if anyone had experienced similar problems and solved them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this has now been solved by upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10.

Unfortunately, it hasn't been solved as in "I fixed it and now I have no problems" - but I've already found the new problems filed as bugs, so hopefully there'll be fixes out soon enough.

I'm considering a downgrade while I'm waiting for the bugfixes to be released, and I'm hoping that the problems I had was due to some configuration error that has now been fixed during the upgrade, but we'll see. If I downgrade and the problem returns, I'll post here.